# Problems with playing stream audio on android Samsung Galaxy S

Tags: android

I just released my first Android app in my life. It's [Audiko](http://audiko.net/ringtone/Android).

I found an error that occurs on Samsung Galaxy S during streaming mp3 file when I use the Android MediaPlayer.

In logs I see this:

```
E/PlayerDriver( 2747): PlayerDriver::it is a not Protected file

E/        ( 2747): IIIIIII Inside Constructor of PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl
E/        ( 2747): IIIIIII Inside Constructor of PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl
E/        ( 2747): IIIIIII Inside Constructor of PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl
E/        ( 2747): IIIIIII Inside Constructor of PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl
E/        ( 2747): IIIIIII Inside Constructor of PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl
E/        ( 2747): IIIIIII Inside Constructor of PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl
E/        ( 2747): IIIIIII Inside Constructor of PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl
E/        ( 2747): IIIIIII Inside Constructor of PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl
E/        ( 2747): IIIIIII Inside Constructor of PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl
E/        ( 2747): IIIIIII Inside Constructor of PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl
E/        ( 2747): IIIIIII Inside Constructor of PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl
D/        ( 2747): PVFile::GetFileName
E/        ( 2747): IIIIIII Inside Constructor of PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl
E/        ( 2747): IIIIIII Inside Constructor of PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl
E/        ( 2747): IIIIIII Inside Constructor of PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl

V/PlayerDriver( 2747): Completed command PLAYER_INIT status=-1
E/PlayerDriver( 2747): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info -1
E/MediaPlayer(13523): error (1, -1)
E/MediaPlayer(13523): Error (1,-1)
```

Any suggestions on what it can be?

Comment: There's nothing special. Just standard using of MediaPlayer API, also it works on any other device except this one. I suppose it's some device specific issue.

Comment: I too am getting reports from users about streaming failing on their Samsung Galaxy S.

Comment: Are you streaming an mp3 to or from the device?

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems sort of like this on some devices. Your best bet is to just temporarily download the file and play that version instead of streaming it. That is, this would work if the ringtone is relatively small, which I would think is typically the case.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something very similar. i use a Galaxy S2 for debugging and while trying to play a live radio stream i got all sort of errors and problems. First thing you have to know is that as some devices support the wma files (Windows Media Audio format) but the Galaxy doesn't so unless you find a way to convert that kind of stream to playable stream, you got a problem there.

The (kind of) solution i found for the problem is the following, as i read a long time ago somewhere what you can do is instead of using `MediaPlayer` and try to stream straight is to use an `InputStream` to read from the audio (right now i worked only with Mp3 because as i said wma wouldn't work) get a few seconds of audio into an mp3 file, and then use the `MediaPlayer` to play that file locally while Rebuffering the next part of the audio into a second file, and then just go back and forth playing those files ( you can set the length of each file )

I leave you part of the code i was trying to implement and worked for buffering and playing the mp3 on my phone, but i didn't continue with the project has i haven't found a sutable solution for wma yet.

```
public void onClick(View v)
        {
            try
            {

                URL url = new URL("http://........./myStation.mp3");
                InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
                long bytesRead = 0; 

                    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();               
                    File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/usbStorage");
                    if(dir.exists()== false) 
                    {
                        dir.mkdirs();
                    }

                File outputSource = new File(dir, "test.mp3");
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputSource);
                //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FileOutputStream: " + outputSource);
                int c;
                int howManyBytes = 12000; 
            //You decide the amount of bytes to read because the live stream while keep on going forver
                while ((c = inputStream.read()) != 10000) 
                {

                    fileOutputStream.write(c);
                    bytesRead++;
                    if (bytesRead > howManyBytes) break;
                }
                fileOutputStream.close();
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.fromFile(outputSource));
                mp.start(); // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("radio", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```